# Parsing value from a large text file

Tags: python

I need to parse a huge text file (100s of GB) and do some analysis. I though of splitting the text file and parse through that block and append values in dictionary similar to below

```
import collections
import re
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0])

bufsize = 65536
with open(path) as infile:
    while True:
        lines = infile.readlines(bufsize)
        if not lines:
            break
        for line in lines:
            temp  = line.split(' ')
            d[temp[0]][0]+=1

            if re.match(r"[2,3].{2}", temp[1]):
                d[temp[0]][1]+=1
            else:
                d[temp[0]][2]+=1
```

I use if condition inside for loop. Will it affect the performance.Is there any other efficient way to do this with less time

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a buffer here. Can't you directly do `for line in lines` instead of wrapping it all in an infinite loop?

Comment: how looks like the data in your file ?

Comment: @AdamSmith Because the file is so huge. If I take all the data for file, it might exhaust the memory

Comment: `for line in lines` iterates by line, it will consume less memory than this approach (unless your lines are over 65536 bytes in size)

Comment: @CédricJulien will be like http log

Comment: and what in the end? you are filling `d` and what then? Post the input file fragment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I will print result based on the values

Comment: @AdamSmith  while True:
        lines = infile.readlines() will be very huge. My file is equivalent to hundreds of GB

Comment: Post the input file fragment and expected result so that you code and logic could be further optimized

Answer (score 0):

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) all you need to do is use context manager:

```
with open(path) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        do_something_with(line)
```

The `with`
 construct is suggested because is handling all the `open/close` file operations even if there is an exception, so ti avoids you to use a `try catch` block.

Moreover the `for line in myfile` is also suggested in the same doc page for memory efficency. I quote from documentation:

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This
>   is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code: `for line in f:  print(line, end='')`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to read the file line by line and process each line accordingly (as @rakwaht suggested)

But, cpu performance is going to be high when you read the file line by line. It reaches `>90%` whenever the program is running.

Now, if you want to avoid that cpu performance hike, introduce a sleep counter (this doesn't need to be in seconds just `0.1 seconds` would do)

```
with open(path) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        foo(line)
        sleep(0.1)
```

Experiment with the sleep timer. For me, when I used `0.1 seconds`, the cpu performance fell down to `6%-7%`. If you need much below than that, you can increase it to `0.3 seconds`. Just try to keep it below `1 second`, other wise your program will be slow as well.

**Note 1**: Always try to reduce the cpu performance. Because, when you are trying to read a 1GB file, it takes quite a bit of time. You don't want the cpu hike for the whole time. Other processes wouldn't work. Now imagine if you have a 4GB file or more than that. CPU is going to be stacked up - by the time you complete your program's execution you will hear that high revolving speed of the system cooling fan - this makes you to not even open another application.

**Note 2**: Also, never try to store anything in memory when you are processing such huge files. Memory usage exponentially increases in these kind of programs. Try to use more of generators